# ANOVA (AOV function) in R: Misleading p_value reported on equal values

Tags: r, anova, p-value

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on the following: I am running ANOVA (aov) to retrieve p_value s for a number of subsets of a larger data set. So I kind of bumped into a subset where my numeric variables/values are equally 36. Because it is a part of a loop ANOVA is still executed along with reporting an seemingly infinitely small p_value 1.2855e-134--> Correct me if I am wrong but the smaller the p_value the higher the probability that the difference between the factors is significantly different?

For simplicity this is the subset:
[sUBSET_FOR_ANOVA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeCFi.jpg)

Here is how I calculate ANOVA and retrieve p_value, where TEMP_DF2 is just the subset you see attached:

#

```
anova_sweep <- aov(TEMP_DF2$GOOD_PTS~TEMP_DF2$MACH,data = TEMP_DF2)
p_value <- summary(anova_sweep)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]]  
p_value <- p_value[1]
```

#

Many thanks for any guidance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate your findings. Let's produce an example dataset with all values being 36:

```
df <- data.frame(gr = rep(letters[1:2], 100),
                 y = 36)
summary(aov(y~gr, data = df))
```

Gives:

```
             Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
gr            1 1.260e-27 1.262e-27       1  0.319
Residuals   198 2.499e-25 1.262e-27
```

Basically, depending on the sample size, we obtain a p-value around 0.3 or so. The F statistic is (by definition) always 1, since the between and within group variances are equal.

Are there results misleading? To some extent, yes. The estimated SS and MS should be 0, `aov` calculates them as very very small. Some other statistical tests in `R` and in some packages check for zero variance and would produce an error, but `aov` apparently does not.

However, more importantly, I would say your data is violating the assumptions of the ANOVA and therefore any result cannot be trusted to base conclusion on. The expectation in R when it comes to statistical tests is usually that it is upon the user to employ the tests in the correct circumstances.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I will have to exclude subsets to run ANOVA on where variances are equal.Many thanks again for explaining this...